# setTimeout not giving the expected output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, settimeout

I have the following code but it doesn't seem to work properly. I cant understand why.

**JS**

```
var updateBoard = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "engine/main.php",
            data: {codes: 2},
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
        setTimeout(updateBoard, 1000);
    };
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['codes'])) {
    echo "test";
}
```

Comment: So call setTimeout(updateBoard, 1000);` on a higher level. Outside function

Comment: what is the issue. what you are expecting from above code?

Comment: @vijayP, I am expecting to get the word `test` in my console every sec. but my code doesnt give any output.

Comment: @Smiranin, calling `setTimeout` outside runs the code only once and gives output only once.

Comment: Can you try setInterval() instead of setTimeout()?

Comment: @Ayan How many times do you want to call the function? Please take into consideration that browsers put restrictions on sending simultaneous requests. If I am not mistaken in the Google Chrome can be no more than seven requests.

Comment: Recursive setTimeout is not no different from the setInterval. Even it is more reliable.

Comment: A) you better set the next timeout withing the success handler to avoid overlapping requests in case one request takes >1s.B) you do have to call your function once before it starts calling itself (unless you just forgot to add this code line)

Comment: @Smiranin - no; there is a big difference between recursive setTime and setInterval. In case of setInterval; we are making request after each 1 seconds without knowing whether previous request's response has come back or not. But in case of setTimeout; we are making next request only if previous request has been completed. So ultimately we are putting less traffic to our server.

Comment: @vijayP, exactly the reason I am using setTimeout in here to be sure of whether the previous request completed.

Comment: @newBee, very true. I forgot to add that line.

Comment: @Ayan - ok thats great..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with following approach:

```
var updateBoard = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "engine/main.php",
            data: {codes: 2},
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                setTimeout(updateBoard, 1000); //calling the function after 1 sec after we get the response
            }
        });

    };

updateBoard(); //calling it right away
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Smiranin said, just call **setTimeout** outside of the function:

```
var updateBoard = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "engine/main.php",
        data: {codes: 2},
        success: function(response) {
           console.log(response)
        }
    })
};
setTimeout(updateBoard, 1000);
```

Or just use **setInterval** instead of SetTimeout

```
setInterval(updateBoard, 1000);
```

Comment: It runs my code once resulting in printing of `test` once only in console.

Comment: @Ayan as I edited just use setInterval instead of setTimeout check: https://jsfiddle.net/onq49tgr/

Comment: @setInterval also worked but I dont like it for overlapping request problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setInterval() if you want to run this in every seconds.

```js
 var updateBoard = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "engine/main.php",
            data: {codes: 2},
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
        
    };
 setInterval(updateBoard, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Interval for backend requests is not a good idea. Imagine you have one requests that takes longer then 1s (e.g. Someone using a high latency connection on mobile). You would end up with a bunch of overlapping requests.